# mod_nss with Apache public Certificate issue

Tags: apache, web-services, certificate, nss

I have replaced `mod_ssl` with `mod_nss` for `FIPS` cryptography and it works great with `Apache` but now we have wildcard certificate which i want to import into NSS database but i don't know how do i import certificate `private key`?

I am using following command

```
certutil -A -d /etc/httpd/alias/ -n "GlobalSign" -t "CT,," -a -i wildcard_domain.crt
```

How do i import private key? or is there something i am missing?

```
[root@web01 ~]# certutil -L -d /etc/httpd/alias

Certificate Nickname                                         Trust Attributes
                                                             SSL,S/MIME,JAR/XPI

cacert                                                       CTu,Cu,Cu
Server-Cert                                                  u,u,u
GlobalSign-Intermediate                                      CT,,
GlobalSign                                                   CTu,u,u
alpha            

                                        u,pu,u
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I'm running across the same thing

Comment: @ChrisWhittle - yes i have solved it, check answer section below

Answer (score 3):

## solution:

Convert crt file in PEM format

## create pem file from original certificate.

```
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in ./ssl.crt/example.com.GlobalSign-2010.crt > /root/example.com.GlobalSign-2010.pem
openssl x509 -inform PEM -in ./ssl.crt/intermediate.GlobalSign.crt > /root/intermediate.GlobalSign.crt.pem
```

## Concatenate PEM certificate in single file, Root crt and Chain crt.

```
cat /root/example.com.GlobalSign-2010.pem /root/intermediate.GlobalSign.crt.pem > /root/example.com-GlogalSign-2010.pem
```

## Export PEM cert and private key in PKCS12 format

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in example.com-GlogalSign-2010.pem -inkey ./ssl.key/example.com.GlobalSign.key -out /root/example.com-Globalsign.p12 -name Example-GlobalSign
```

## Import PKCS12 (.p12) certificate in NSS DB

```
pk12util -i /root/example.com-Globalsign.p12 -d /etc/httpd/alias
```

You can verify your certificate using following command

```
certutil -L -d /etc/httpd/alias -n Example-GlobalSign
```

**Notes:** put `Example-GlobalSign` nickname in nss.conf config file and Voila!!